# SQL select rows based on wildcards and = in IN Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a situation where I need to select Customer_IDs whose items that contain the keyword "box" and "phone", which mean, the minimum condition is at least 2 rows, one for box, one for phone, both need to show up for that customer_ID, order doesn't matter, but the challenge is for example, phone3105557890, the sting part is always the same, "phone", but the final part vary,

sample data

```
    Customer_ID     item             year
1   222             box              2018
2   222         phone3105557890      2018
3   222             box              2017
4   444             box              2018
5   444             pen              2018
6   444            apple             2018
7   666             table            2018
8   666             box              2018
9   666         phone9995467777      2018
```

expected result

```
    Customer_ID     item             year
1   222             box              2018
2   222         phone3105557890      2018
3   222             box              2017
4   666             table            2018
5   666             box              2018
6   666         phone9995467777      2018
```

Warning: using `select customer_ID from myTable where item = 'box' or item like 'phone%'`  can't give me what I want coz I need both box and phone rows both show up as a minimum requirement. that's why 444 will be filtered out.

my attempt:

```
select customer_ID from myTable where item IN ('box','phone')
```

but phone need a wildcard, `where item LIKE 'phone%'`

how to combine two above logic to make it work?  do I need to declare a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` and `HAVING`

```
select *
from myTable
where customer_ID in (select customer_ID 
                      from myTable 
                      where item = 'box' or item like 'phone%' 
                      group by customer_ID 
                      having count(distinct case when item like 'phone%' then 1 else item end) >= 2)
```

Comment: can your code guarantee that at least 1 box and 1 phone, look like if there's a situation where two (item = box) but no phone%, counting > 2 still meet your condition? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Good catch Learn i just made and edit that will take that into consideration. Also thanks @ErickBrandt

Comment: what if another situation, there're 2 phone%, but no box, does it meet your condition? coz I'm not sure if the distinct trigger first or the case when trigger first?

Comment: If there is two phones and no box it will not be returned. The predicate is evaluated first and the case expression also handles this case. Feel free to test it

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer_ID from myTable where item = 'box' or item like 'phone%'
```

Comment: you code can't give me what I want coz I need both box and phone rows both show up as a minimum requirement. the customer_ID  = 444 will not excluded due to where item = 'box'. I need both condition meet